# Street View for Google for Cardboard

Tags: google-street-view, google-cardboard

As I am quite novice in Google Maps & Cardboard development, I wonder from where to start to develop Street View for Google Cardboard. I would actually like to have such an application and include some proprietary features.

I know that Google has developed such an application: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.street

Do I actually need to develop another Streeview application or can I take the Google Streetview application and just add a layer containing my data on top of it?

Thanks.

Fabrice

Comment: Did you discover a solution?